# How can I place a "searching within" div in the search bar after a user clicks a button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Say a user clicks a button that says "Search only within footwear." I want my search bar to reflect then this filter has been added by adding a small grey box to the beginning that says "Searching within footwear" like so:

[image]

I'd like the search input to begin after this box appears, and have the placeholder text shift over as well. What is the best way to implement this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Including it at the left side of the input like this introduces some complications, because there's no way to embed an image inside of an input. You might consider adding the text over the input instead if you have the design freedom to do so.

To keep it on the left you can reduce the width of the input, and then add the filter before it, either as a pseudo-element, or some element that you populate with the text "Footwear".

Then, you match up the styling of the Footwear element with the input, so that it looks like a continuous input.

Something like [this](https://codepen.io/BrandonKerr/pen/GMZMry).

Or, if you can use a CSS framework, Bootstrap supports this behavior now. 
Try something like [this](https://codepen.io/BrandonKerr/pen/KXzXbP):

```
<form>
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-xs-5">
      <div class="input-group">
          <span class="input-group-addon transparent"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user">Footwear</span></span>
          <input class="form-control left-border-none" placeholder="User Name" type="text" name="username">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Either way, you can then dynamically change the value of the filter text using Javascript, whenever the user clicks on one of the filter buttons.

Answer (score 2):

There's infinite ways to implement this. Which is the best depends mostly on your project's needs and scope. If you are going to add a lot of dynamic behavior to your page, I'd suggest you begin to take a look at modern view frameworks like Vue, React, Angular 2 and similar.

To get to the point and following what @Bricky says, you could simply put a div where the word "Footwear" would need to be, and populate it later via a `click` event.

See this example:

```js
'use strict';

$('.filter').click(function (_) {
  $('.current-filter').text('Footwear');
});
```

```css
.toolbar {
  padding: 15px;
  background: #ff6347;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
      -ms-flex-pack: center;
          justify-content: center;
}
.search-wrapper {
  display: -webkit-inline-box;
  display: -ms-inline-flexbox;
  display: inline-flex;
  width: 300px;
  background-color: #808080;
  color: #fff;
}
.search-wrapper .current-filter:not(:empty) {
  padding: 3px;
}
.search-wrapper input {
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
      -ms-flex-positive: 1;
          flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="toolbar">
  <div class="search-wrapper">
    <div class="current-filter"></div>
    <input placeholder="Search..." />
  </div>
</div>
<div>
  <button class="filter">Footwear</button>
</div>
```

I've used some flexbox properties to maintain the box always the same size.